# Effective update for records in partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql I have created a master table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_master(
  id text NOT NULL,
  active bool NOT NULL,
  field text NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY LIST (active);
```

The table is split into active and inactive table.
Active is split into multiple partitions by hash:

```
CREATE TABLE table_inactive PARTITION OF table_master
    FOR VALUES in (FALSE)

CREATE TABLE table_active PARTITION OF table_master
    FOR VALUES in (TRUE)
    PARTITION BY HASH(field)

CREATE TABLE table_active_p0 PARTITION OF table_active FOR VALUES WITH (modulus 0, remainder 16)
....
```

I'm trying to update records effectively partition by partition.

1. `update table_active_p0 set active=false where field like '%DELETED%'` is not allowed because of condition violation.
2. `update table_master set active=false where field like '%DELETED%' and tableoid = 'table_active_p0'::regclass::oid;` still performs lookup over all partitions
3. `update table_master set active=false where field like '%DELETED% and field in (select field from table_active_p0)` also performs lookup over all partitions

I'm running out of ideas how to perform update that would change a partition without accessing every partition.

Comment: Why not `update table_master set active=false where active and field ...`? But I doubt the planner will ever evaluate the sub-partitions with a LIKE condition like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in my case every partition is big and update is taking longer than allowed. But update of single partition is much faster and fits into timeframes.
I'm plan to execute these request regularly with a job, so i'm trying to split whole update job into multiple chunks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this.  If you used RANGE partitioning, it would be pretty easy.  Yet another reason that HASH partitioning kind of sucks.